# Почему не вылетает 2 исключения подряд?

Tags: java, исключения, scanner

Уважаемые, вопрос. Причём сразу скажу, что если Вы не шарите за нюансы работы методов класса Scanner и связанных с ними исключений - **смело проходите дальше**.

Тестируемый код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Введите x: ");
    int x = console.nextInt(); // "\n".

    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Введите y: ");
            int y = console.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            console.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

[Пример в онлайн](https://replit.com/@work8play/Programm-2).

Мы присвоили переменной `x` какое-нибудь число, а дальше начинает работать цикл, который не прервётся до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт какое-либо целое число. Допустим он пишет какую-либо чушь. Перехватываем исключение ввода не int'a, очищаем сканнер console командой `cosnole.nextLine();` и едем дальше снова и снова. Но вот не задача, перед самым первым витком цикла мы же уже считали число и присвоили его переменной `x`. В самом же сканнере незримо остаётся символ переноса строки "**\n**" после работы `int x = console.nextInt();` Далее, допустим, пользователь пишет любое слово и в сканере уже следующая картина: **\nслово\n**.

Вылетает исключение;
перехватываем;
используем console.nextLine(); для очистки сканнера; но напомню, что в сканнере **\nслово\n** и данный метод должен споткнуться о первый **\n** и дальше передать на новый виток цикла **слово\n**;
далее опять перехват исключения и уже 2-е срабатывание `console.nextLine();` очистит сканнер полностью, дойдя до последнего **\n**;
и таким образом, фраза "Введите y: " должна запринтится дважды, однако этого не происходит.
Почему?! Куда исчезает символ переноса строки после первого перехвата исключения у `int y = console.nextInt();`
Я знаю, что в штатном режиме при втором по счёту вводе числа, если в начале в console было: **\n**
мы ввели число;
в console: **\nчисло\n**
число считывает, первый символ **\n** также отлетает и в console остаётся: **\n**
Но если речь об исключении, то
 в console: **\n**
вводим слово;

в console: **\nслово\n**;

вылетает исключение и, что же, получается, что оно скипает первый **\n**? И в console остаётся **слово\n**? Такая механика работы? Иначе,  я это никак не могу объяснить! Получается, что исключение у метода `console.nextInt();` при любых раскладах скипает первый символ \n, если таковой там изначально имелся. Но я в этом не уверен, потому что не знаю механики работы этого исключения. Всё же, я новичок, но новичок дотошный. Заранее respect тому, кто сможет объяснить!
И да, тесты должны быть одного вида, чтобы расшарить эту проблему:
1. какое-либо число
2. какое-либо *слово*

Comment: `nextLine()` не спотыкается. Попробуйте вместо `слово` ввести просто энтер и увидите, что сканнер ждет строку, игнорируя символы конца строки. И как только вы введете строку, он вернет все, исключая концы строк (см javaDoc)

Comment: Я видел ваш ответ на вчерашний мой вопрос. Вот вам контаргумент: https://replit.com/@work8play/Programm-1 В этом коде, если не очистить сканнер после инициализации переменной x, то console.nextLine(); именно споткнётся об него, и метод console.hasNextInt(); вернёт false 2 раза, следовательно и строка "Введите y: " запринтится 2 раза.

Comment: Я понимаю, что ни у кого не желания особо копаться в этих моментах. Типа работает, да и ладно. Но я человек скурпулёзный. Ничего не поделать. :(

Comment: @work8play очень хороший вопрос, сейчас отвечу!!

Comment: Кажется, я понял ваше замешательство. Все дело в данном случае не в исключении, а в порядке вызова `nextInt()` и `nextLine()`. Если после ввода числа  сканнер его считывает, то в буфере остается `\n`. Если в таком состоянии мы вызываем `nextLine()`, то вернется пустая строка, т.к. сканнер распознвет, что мы ввели нечто вроде `"" + \n`. Но! Если после этого конца строки будет еще какое-то слово, то первый конец строки скипнется и сканнер считает только слово до конца строки, исключая конец строки как и написано в контракте метода `nextLine()`

Comment: Если бы работало именно так, то фраза "Введите y:" не принтилась бы 2 раза в коде через цикл "без исключений". Я не сомневаюсь, что вы человек  со знаниями, но я вас не понимаю.

Comment: Что такое `в коде через цикл "без исключений"`?

Comment: это вторая ссылка, на код, которая в комментарии выше. Я там не использую конструкцию try catch

Comment: А, ну да. Я как раз этот случай и описал. Смотрите, в строке 8 вы считываете правильное целое число, введенное с клавы. Оно записывается в переменную `x` и в буффере остается `\n`. Затем, поскольку `hasNextInt()` вернет `false`,  печатаем `Введите у:` и считываем (строка 16). И вот тут сканнер видит конец строки, и поскольку это последний конец строки, он считывает все что до него, а это пустая строка (""). Затем цикл идет дальше, видим, что все еще нет целого числа, снова просим ввести у и снова ждем ввода... итд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень хороший вопрос! Я знаю, как работает `Scanner`, но все равно пришлось  покопаться, чтобы однозначно ответить на этот вопрос.

Расскажу порядок работы сканнера при вызове `scanner.next()` и аналогов для примитивов (`nextDouble()`, `nextInt()`), чтобы помочь вам разобраться.

1. `Scanner` берет ввод и делит его на так называемые токены с помощью делимитеров. Считайте токен просто кусочком строки. Делимитер - паттерн, который может быть каким угодно, например, `(\\s)`, то есть пробел (вы не задаете делимитер, поэтому у вас делимитер по умолчанию, о котором скажу далее).
2. `Scanner` идет по токенам, пока токены не закончатся, либо пока не будет найден подходящий токен (например, число, в случае с `nextInt()`), либо пока парсинг токена не вызовет исключение. (Но, по моему предположению после многих попыток тестирования, первое исключение игнорируется, если оно вызвано токеном с предыдущего ввода).
3. Когда выполнился проход по токенам (пункт 2), все последующие токены и делимитеры (если есть) остаются в сканнере, а пройденные удаляются.

Вы не задаете свой делимитер, поэтому используется делимитер по умолчанию, который можно получить так: `System.out.println(console.delimiter().pattern());`.

На выводе мы получим `\p{javaWhitespace}+`. Я был удивлен этому ответу, т.к. он меня поставил в тупик, я не знал, что такое `javaWhiteSpace`. Погугля, я нашел [ответ](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/04.html):

> There are four other white space characters in Java, the horizontal tab, the form feed, the carriage return, and the linefeed.

То есть, как видим, одним и делимитеров является перенос строки по умолчанию.

---

Теперь поясню, как работает `nextLine()`, чтобы понять отличие. Данный метод просто достает первый токен ввода сканнера (даже если токен пустой), а делимитером является не делимитер сканнера, а только перенос строки.

---

Теперь перейдем к примеру, чтобы объяснить работу сканнера получше:

Когда вы вводите `x` (к примеру, `5`), у вас в сканнере появляется `5\n`. Сканнер видит один делимитер и 2 токена: `'5'` и `''`. Он начинает их парсить, первый токен подходит под `Integer` паттерн, поэтому `nextInt()` возвращает `5`. В сканнере остается один делимитер `\n` и один токен `''`.

Далее ваша программа просит `y`.
Прежде чем просить ввод ваш ввод, `Scanner` посмотрит, что у него есть внутри из `System.in`:

1. `\n` - делимитер.
2. `''` - токен.
   Дальше `Scanner` парсит токены (`''` в нашем случае) и если не находит ничего интересного, не бросает исключение, а просит ввод, блокируя программу (сканнер не бросит эксепшен до запроса ввода, только если уже после ввода не будет ничего, что являлось бы `Integer`, тогда уже бросит эксепшен).

И так, `Scanner` ничего не нашел (`\n` и `''` в нашем случае) и попросил ввод.

Давайте сделаем необычный ввод, чтобы отразить полноценно работу сканнера и вы поняли принцип. Введем '5 blablabla'.

Теперь у нас в сканнер ситуация такая:

1. `5` - токен с текущего ввода.
2. `' '` - делимитер с текущего ввода.
3. `blablabla` - токен с текущего ввода.
4. `\n` - делимитер с текущего ввода.

`Scanner` смотрит первый токен, видит там `Integer`, берет его и оставляет остальное у себя, программа не крашится, тк токен `5` валиден, а `blablabla` - уже совсем другой токен.

---

Вот так работает `Scanner`.
Подытожим, почему `Выбрать y:` показывается только один раз. Это так потому, что `nextInt()` и подобные методы смотрять не на один токен, а на сколько угодно токенов до конца или до exception. А `nextLine()` берет только первый токен до разрыва строки.

Comment: если будут вопросы еще, то пишите, возможно какой-то момент не затронул и что-то будет не понятно.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Сейчас внимательно всё прочитаю.

Comment: @work8play вам спасибо за такой вопрос!))

Comment: @Maxgmer не совсем понял последние 3 предложения. `nextLine()` в секции `catch` обязательно, т.к. мы "чистим" буффер не только от пустых символов, но и от всего не-числового ввода, который мы делаем в цикле, тогда мы можем зайти в бесконечный цикл

Comment: @Maxgmer  Слушайте, а не слишком нагло с мой стороны будет кинуть вам link на конфу в Discord чтобы всё это проговорить? Не думаю, что займёт больше 10 минут.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець ой тут ошибся, спасибо, поставлю upvote вам.

Comment: @work8play можно, maxgmer #7043 мой дискорд

Comment: https://discord.gg/GXdfF2Uf

Answer (score 3):

В свое время тоже долго разбирался в работе сканнера. И вот этот простой код с объяснением поставил все на свои места. Может, и вам поможет:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * http://mastefanov.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/programmingJava.
         * lec3_.4Scanner.pdf
         */
        
        double doubleFoo;
        int integerBar;
        float floatQuiz;
        long longBaz;
        String token;
        String line;
        
        try (Scanner stdInScanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            doubleFoo = stdInScanner.nextDouble();
            integerBar = stdInScanner.nextInt();
            floatQuiz = stdInScanner.nextFloat();
            longBaz = stdInScanner.nextLong();
            token = stdInScanner.next();
            line = stdInScanner.nextLine();
        }
        
        System.out.printf("double=%f\nint=%d\nfloat=%f\nlong=%d\ntoken=%s\nline=%s\n", doubleFoo, integerBar, floatQuiz,
                longBaz, token, line);
        System.out.println("over");
    }

}

/*
 * Работа программы: 1,1 2 3 4 5 double=1,100000 int=2 float=3,000000 long=4
 * token=5 line= over Более детально работу метода printf() мы рассмотрим в
 * следующем параграфе, в общем смысл таков – первым параметром задается
 * форматирующая строка, содержащая специальные группы символов (начинающиеся со
 * знака %), которые в результате заменяются соответствующим значением из списка
 * параметров. Пользовательский ввод обозначен зеленым цветом, вывод программы –
 * черным. В случае с вещественными и целыми числами все выглядит логично.
 * Пользователь вводит число, после чего нажимает enter. Введённое им значение
 * попадает в поток System.in и считывается сканнером. В каждой строке
 * присутствует только одно число. При этом с помощью метода nextFloat() (и
 * nextDouble()) мы можете считать не только вещественные числа, но и целые (но
 * в результате они все равно будут представлены как вещественные). Таким
 * образом, мы успешно считываем 4 числа и записываем их в переменные,
 * соответственно doubleFoo, integerBar, floatQuiz, longBaz. Однако дальше
 * проявляется особенность метода nextLine(). После методов, считывающих числа,
 * идут вызовы next() и nextLine(): String token = stdInScanner.next(); String
 * line = stdInScanner.nextLine(); Казалось бы, после ввода пользователем числа
 * 5 (которое логично считывается методом next() и записывается в переменную
 * token), программа должна ожидать ввода строки – но этого не происходит, она
 * завершает свою работу, а переменная line в итоге не содержит никакого
 * значения. Давайте рассмотрим, что попадает в поток, когда пользователь вводит
 * 5 и нажимает enter. Во входном потоке оказывается последовательность бит,
 * которая соответствует символу ‘5’ и символу «конец строки». Конец строки – по
 * умолчанию является разделителем токенов, поэтому все, что было до него, было
 * считано методом next(), и маркер, который показывает текущее положение в
 * потоке, устанавливается после 5, но перед «концом строки». Затем вызывается
 * метод nextLine(), который успешно обнаруживает оставшуюся группу символов,
 * соответствующих «концу строки» и успешно считывает его. Но поскольку никаких
 * символов между маркером и концом строки нет, то в буфер ничего не заносится,
 * и следовательно, в результате методом ничего не возвращается и в переменную
 * line ничего не записывается. Пара слов, относительно группы символов «конец
 * строки». По стандарту, любое совместимое с Юникодом приложение должно
 * воспринимать как перевод строки каждый из нижеследующих символов: LF
 * (U+000A): англ. line feed — подача строки; CR (U+000D): англ. carriage return
 * — возврат каретки; CR + LF – рассматривается как один перевод строки, а не 2
 * NEL (U+0085): англ. next line — переход на следующую строку; LS (U+2028):
 * англ. line separator — разделитель строк; PS (U+2029): англ. paragraph
 * separator — разделитель абзацев. В стандартных текстовых файлах, использующих
 * кодировку ASCII в зависимости от операционной системы, в качестве разделителя
 * строк могут использоваться сомволы: LF – Unix, FreeBSD, MacOS… CR – (старые
 * версии MacOS) CR + LF – MSDOS, Windows. Рассмотрим еще один пример
 * пользовательского ввода предыдущей программы: 1,1 2 3 4 5 678 9
 * double=1,100000 int=2 float=3,000000 long=4 token=5 line= 678 9 over
 * По-прежнему, символы, вводимые пользователем помечены зеленым цветом. Этот
 * пример показывает несколько нюансов: 1) По-умолчанию, «лишние» пробелы при
 * поиске токенов во входном потоке с помощью метода класса Scanner
 * игнорируются. 2) Если в предыдущем случае все методы считывания блокировали
 * работу программы, пока пользователь не введет что-либо, то сейчас блокировка
 * осуществляется только методом nextDouble() и next(). 3) После считывания
 * какого-либо токена, остальные биты из потока не удаляются и могут быть
 * считаны последующими вызовами методов чтения. В данном случае, метод
 * nextDouble() блокирует выполнение программы. После того как пользователь ввел
 * строку «1,1 2 3 4» метод считал токен 1,1 и поместил маркер чтения сразу
 * после него. Следующий метод считал все пробелы, затем 2 и поместил маркер
 * сразу за символом 2. Затем в программе подряд вызывается еще 2 метода,
 * которые считывают, соответственно 3 и 4 не блокируя работу программы в
 * ожидании ввода. 4) Последняя строка показывает, что маркер чтения
 * устанавливается методами nextX() сразу после считанного токена (и следующие
 * за ним разделители считываются уже следующим вызовом nextX()). next() считал
 * 5, а nextLine() вернул строку из символов, между 5 и концом строки (включая
 * пробел между 5 и 678).
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

Уже есть хороший ответ со всеми подробностями. Не буду повторяться.

Скажу только что [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) поддерживает две тактики работы с входным потоком: чтение по токенам (грубо говоря по словам) и по строкам. Все методы [next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()), [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), [nextLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong()) и т.п. работают с токенами. А метод [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong()) работает со строками.

Теперь к делу. Если вы хотите сделать интерактивный ввод удобный для пользователя-человека, работайте со строками. Считывайте строку целиком, затем преобразуйте в значение нужного типа. В случае ошибки со сканнером ничего делать не надо, никакого мусора во входном потоке нет:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerLines {
    private static int readInt(Scanner s, String prompt) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String line = s.nextLine();
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(line);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Error: wrong integer");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            int v = readInt(s, "[" + i + "] Enter integer > ");
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] The integer is " + v + '\n');
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ java ScannerLines 
> [0] Enter integer > 12
> [0] The integer is 12
>
> [1] Enter integer > 23f
> Error: wrong integer
> [1] Enter integer > 23 34
> Error: wrong integer
> [1] Enter integer > 23
> [1] The integer is 23
>
> [2] Enter integer > 34
> [2] The integer is 34
> ```

Работа с токенами менее удобна. Пользователь может вводить числа вперед и это никак не поправить. В случае ошибки пропускайте ошибочный токен (метод [next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())), а не всю строку (метод [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())):

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTokens {
    private static int readInt(Scanner s, String prompt) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            try {
                return s.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Error: wrong integer");
                s.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            int v = readInt(s, "[" + i + "] Enter integer > ");
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] The integer is " + v + '\n');
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ java ScannerTokens 
> [0] Enter integer > 12
> [0] The integer is 12
>
> [1] Enter integer > 23f
> Error: wrong integer
> [1] Enter integer > 23 34
> [1] The integer is 23
>
> [2] Enter integer > [2] The integer is 34
> ```

Повторюсь, пользователь может ввести несколько чисел на одной строке, у нас нет хорошего метода остановить его.

Пишете интерактивный ввод - работайте со строками. Пишете ввод из потока - работайте с токенами. И я бы не стал делать тут обработку ошибок с переспрашиванием, роботу она ни к чему.

Хотите совместить оба подхода? Подумайте ещё раз. Вы или получите странный интерактивный ввод или будете игнорировать ошибки при вводе из потока.